# Need output of a comma separated string in table format

Tags: sql-server

I have an input like 'A,B,1,2 \N C,D,5,8 \N' in a string format with comma separator and I want output like below

```
col1  col2 col3 col4
A     B     1   2
C     D     5   8
```

Comment: Since you've tagged it as sql-server, what version are you using?

Comment: Personally, I'd open the string in Notepad++ and use `Replace \n with FOO` (or any other value I could guarantee would not be a real value) and then use `Extended search (including \n,\r,...`) and replace `FOO` with '\n'. I would then save this file as a .csv file and in Management Studio right click the database, and use  `Tasks -> Import...` and select to import from a flat file, and then set up the import as you'd like.

Comment: This is assuming that `\N` is indeed the value '\N', and not a new row (seeing as you claimed it was a string, and not a file or anything). If it was a new row, I'd merely save to a .csv and import using the same approach as in my previous comment.

Comment: Iam using sql server management studio 2017

Comment: You need any splitting function to accomplish this. First apply it with \N separator and then with ',' separator